# How can I stop my affiliation from creating a page break on my title page?

Tags: page-breaking, titles, authblk, affiliation

When my code looks like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{hanging}

\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{authblk}

\title{My Document}
\author{suitvertices}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{doublespace}
\section{Introduction}
\section{Conclusion}
\end{doublespace}
\section*{References}

\end{document}
```

The first section starts on my title page (which is what I want).  However, when I change my preamble by adding `\affil` (in the place shown below):

```
\title{My Document}
\author{suitvertices}
\affil{My University}
\begin{document}
```

A huge space appears and my first section is pushed to a new page (which I don't want).
How can I prevent this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! When I try your code with `\affil` I get no shift -- all is on the first page and there is only one page then

Comment: I wouldn't use `\begin{doublespace}` and `\end{doublespace}`, but rather `\doublespacing` and `\singlespacing`. Assuming you *must* use double spacing.

Comment: @egreg I'll try that! (And yes, I'm being forced into doublespacing... I would not have chosen it)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I added some packages in which were in my code, which I had omitted as I thought they had no impact (and I was trying to keep my example short.  Does this affect it?

Comment: @eliyahu-g: I've tried and there is no peculiar behaviour. You've got `setspace` twice and `hyperref` should be the last package to be included. So altogether: Nope, your problem must be elsewhere, perhaps an outdated package?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer That's possible.  I'm using Overleaf to compile my code.  Could that be responsible?  I'm going to add screenshots to see if that helps.  Thank you again!

Comment: @eliyahu-g: Well, I've never used Overleaf, I can't say anything about that

Comment: The difference between the code posted here and the one from the screenshot is obvious: Two more `\sections` within `doublespace` environment -- since each sections has it's space above and below the title it will add extra space to the first page and finally the page is filled, all within the `doublespace` shifted to the next page. That `doublespace` is perhaps the main cause

Comment: @ChristianHupfer That worked! If you want to make that into an answer, I would love to upvote and accept it!  Thank you for all your help!

Comment: @eliyahu-g: I can't answer it, because I don't know what worked? Removing the `doublespace` stuff?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Unclear? Or answer anyway?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `\begin{doublespace}...\end{doublespace}`, but use `\doublespacing` rather, since this will add too much vertical spacings.

Adding `\affil` does not lead to wrap over to the next page.

In order to restrict the effect of `\doublespacing`, use an outer group with `{}` or `\begingroup...\endgroup` -- see the screenshot for the differences.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hanging}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{My Document}
\author{eliyahug}
\affil{My University}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
{%
\doublespacing
\section{Introduction}
\section{Conclusion}
\section*{References}
}

\section{Introduction}
\section{Conclusion}
\section*{References}
\end{document}
```

[image]